# Populate grid <div> & <p> with JSON data file

Tags: html, css, json

Have received help previously when importing JSON data into a table but this time we need a responsive & flexible layout and are using a grid, div, p and CSS styling approach.

We are displaying thumbnail "cards" of the latest members to join/renew membership in our group - the number of cards can vary between 2-6 to be displayed at at time and can change frequently

When a user visits the web page we want the JSON data to populate the flexible responsive grid with the thumbnail cards.

The card data comes via a correctly formatted JSON file that is created and uploaded to the web site by a 3rd party app.

Data required to be used is:

- Type
- Year
- Member Page URL
- Member Image Url
- Member Name
- Member Group
- Member Company
- Member Classification
- Ideally we want to either generate in the script or can import the alt text and the title text for each member image (not essential but would be a bonus)

The current hard coded displayed result looks like this:
[image: responsive hard coded result] 
This is an example of the working hardcoded code:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.newmembers {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(155px,175px));
    grid-auto-rows: 370px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
}

.member {
    background: rgba(255, 213, 70, 0.3);
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;
}
.type {
    color: #1f7665;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 5px 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
   .year {
    color: #1f7665;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-small;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
} 
.thumb {
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 160px;
    max-height: 160px;
    min-width: 160x;
    max-width: 160px;
    object-position: center top;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.thumb:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    background:#00CCCC;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%);
    filter: grayscale(10%);
}

.membername {
    color: #1f7665;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px;
}

.group {
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px;
}

.company {
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px;
}

.classification {
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: x-small;
}

.info {
    margin: 10px;
}

</style>

<div class="newmembers">  

<!-- We want to populate a div like this 3,4,5 or 6 times with data from the correctly formated JSON file -->
<div class="member">
    <p class="type">* RENEWING *</p>
    <p class="year">Year: THREE</p>
        <a class="memurl" href="https://example.com/brownsville.html#59e5c8">
            <img class="thumb" 
                alt="MEMBER PROFILE: Andy Smith - Smithville, Andys Lawns, Gardening" 
                title="MEMBER PROFILE:&#013Andy Smith&#013Smithvile&#013Andys Laws&#013Gardening" 
                src="https://example.com/brownsville.html/u/#59e5c8.jpg"
            >
        </a>
    <p class="info">
        <p class="membername">Andy Smith</p>
        <p class="group">Smithville</p>
        <p class="company">Andys Lawns</p>
        <p class="classification">Gardening</p>
    </p>
</div>

<!-- We want to populate a div like this 3,4,5 or 6 times with data from the correctly formated JSON file -->
<div class="member">
    <p class="type">* RENEWING *</p>
    <p class="year">Year: FOUR</p>
        <a class="memurl" href="https://example.com/brownsville.html#5a2f86">
            <img class="thumb" 
                alt="MEMBER PROFILE: Dave Brown -  Brownville, Daves Paint, Paint" 
                title="MEMBER PROFILE:&#013Dave Brown&#013Brownville&#013Daves Paint&#013Paint" 
                src="https://example.com/u/5a2f86.jpg"
            >
        </a>
    <p class="info">
        <p class="membername">Dave Brown</p>
        <p class="group">Brownsville</p>
        <p class="company">Daves Paint</p>
        <p class="classification">Paint</p>
    </p>
</div>

<!-- more "member" divs here -->

</div>
```

Our JSON file will look like this but can be altered to whatever is required:

```
[
{ "type":"* RENEWING *", "year":"THREE", "memurl":"https://example.com/smithville.html#5a2f81", "memimgsrc":"https://example.com/smithville.html/u/#59e5c8.jpg", "membername":"Andy Smith","group":"Smithville","company":"Andys Lawn","classification":"Gardening" },
{ "type":"* RENEWING *", "year":"FOUR", "memurl":"https://example.com/brownsville.html#5a2f86", "memimgsrc":"https://example.com/brownsville.html/u/#5a2f86.jpg", "membername":"Dave Brown","group":"Brownsville","company":"Daves Paint","classification":"Paint" },
{ "type":"* NEW *", "year":"ONE", "memurl":"https://example.com/applegate.html#5b3a51", "memimgsrc":"https://example.com/applegate.html/u/#5b3a51.jpg", "membername":"May Apple","group":"Applegate","company":"Marys Conserves","classification":"Canning" }
];
```

We have used the following script to import data in to a table but how can we get this to work with the above example?

```
<!-- We have used this load to populate a table from JSON and it works perfect -->
<script>
    //first add an event listener for page load
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", get_json_data, false ); // get_json_data is the function name that will fire on page load

    //this function is in the event listener and will execute on page load
    function get_json_data(){
        // Relative URL of external json file
        var json_url = 'example.json';

        //Build the XMLHttpRequest (aka AJAX Request)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {//when a good response is given do this

                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // convert the response to a json object
                append_json(data);// pass the json object to the append_json function
            }
        }
        //set the request destination and type
        xmlhttp.open("POST", json_url, true);
        //set required headers for the request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // send the request
        xmlhttp.send(); // when the request completes it will execute the code in onreadystatechange section
    }

    // FUNCTION TO ADD OR CREATE "member" DIVS NEEDS TO HERE 
    //need function to add json data to the div 'newmembers' and make new div? 
    // No idea 

    function append_json(data){
        var member = document.getElementById('newmembers');
        data.forEach(function(object) {

NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE 

        });
    }
</script>
```

Assistance would be awesome, let me know if additional information or clarification is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, you can use what you've got as your hard coded as a template.

We'll keep the template as HTML, do you really want to go change javascript for a layout change?

I've removed the ajax logic as what you have should be fine.

I've also left some work for you to do with the `alt` and `title` attributes, but you should have enough to work with.

```js
var postData = [{
    "type": "* RENEWING *",
    "year": "THREE",
    "memurl": "https://example.com/smithville.html#5a2f81",
    "memimgsrc": "https://example.com/smithville.html/u/#59e5c8.jpg",
    "membername": "Andy Smith",
    "group": "Smithville",
    "company": "Andys Lawn",
    "classification": "Gardening"
  },
  {
    "type": "* RENEWING *",
    "year": "FOUR",
    "memurl": "https://example.com/brownsville.html#5a2f86",
    "memimgsrc": "https://example.com/brownsville.html/u/#5a2f86.jpg",
    "membername": "Dave Brown",
    "group": "Brownsville",
    "company": "Daves Paint",
    "classification": "Paint"
  },
  {
    "type": "* NEW *",
    "year": "ONE",
    "memurl": "https://example.com/applegate.html#5b3a51",
    "memimgsrc": "https://example.com/applegate.html/u/#5b3a51.jpg",
    "membername": "May Apple",
    "group": "Applegate",
    "company": "Marys Conserves",
    "classification": "Canning"
  }
];

function append_json(data) {
  //Set Up the template
  var s = $("#postTemplate")[0].innerHTML.trim();
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  holder.innerHTML = s;
  var template = holder.childNodes;

  var member = document.getElementById('newmembers');
  data.forEach(function(object) {

    //Clone Template
    var newItem = $(template).clone();

    //Populate it
    $(newItem).find(".type").html(object.type);
    $(newItem).find(".year").html($(newItem).find(".year").html() + " " + object.year);
    $(newItem).find(".memurl").attr("href", object.memurl);
    var img = $(newItem).find(".thumb")
    $(img).attr("src", object.memimgsrc).attr("alt", $(img).attr("alt") + object.membername + " " + "etc")
      .attr("title", $(img).attr("title") + object.membername + " finish this off");
    $(newItem).find(".membername").html(object.membername);
    $(newItem).find(".group").html(object.group);
    $(newItem).find(".company").html(object.company);
    $(newItem).find(".classification").html(object.classification);
    //Append it

    $(".newmembers").append(newItem);

  });
}

$("document").ready(function() {
  append_json(postData);
});
```

```css
.newmembers {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(155px, 175px));
  grid-auto-rows: 370px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
}

.member {
  background: rgba(255, 213, 70, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;
}

.type {
  color: #1f7665;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.year {
  color: #1f7665;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-small;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.thumb {
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 160px;
  max-height: 160px;
  min-width: 160x;
  max-width: 160px;
  object-position: center top;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.thumb:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #00CCCC;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%);
  filter: grayscale(10%);
}

.membername {
  color: #1f7665;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px;
}

.group {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
}

.company {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
}

.classification {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: x-small;
}

.info {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="newmembers">

  <!-- Template for our posts -->
  <script type="text/template" id="postTemplate">
    <div class="member">
      <p class="type"></p>
      <p class="year">Year:</p>
      <a class="memurl" href="">
        <img class="thumb" alt="MEMBER PROFILE: " title="MEMBER PROFILE: " src="">
      </a>
      <!-- Replaced p  with div, can't nest p tags -->
      <div class="info">
        <p class="membername"></p>
        <p class="group"></p>
        <p class="company"></p>
        <p class="classification"></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </script>




</div>
```

Comment: Thanks JoN P- perfect answer - used same loader and your appending code-never would have got that! Was struggling to get CRs in the Title text as due to the java parsing #013; was not recognized. I used \x0A instead.  `code`         $(img).attr("src", object.memimgsrc).attr("alt", $(img).attr("alt") + object.membername + " - " + object.group + " - "  +  object.company + " - " +object.classification)
            .attr("title", $(img).attr("title") + "\x0A\x0A" + object.membername + "\x0A" + object.group + "\x0A"  +  object.company + "\x0A" +object.classification); `code`